# Removing attribute modifiers on dropped items

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Just a quick question: what path would I use to remove all attribute modifiers from a dropped item?

ive used with no avail:

```
Item.tag.AttributeModifiers

Item.AttributeModifiers

AttributeModifiers
```

ive also tried the `[]` at the end as well

Comment: Which ones have you tried the `[]` on?

Comment: I'm still curious, why did it not work the first time? Did you not try the code in my solution before?

Comment: I think my selector was off. it was probably picking up a different item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct path is:

```
Item.tag.AttributeModifiers[]
```

to remove all attribute modifiers from a dropped item. If you've already tried this, then maybe your setup is wrong.

The command you'll need is:

```
/data remove entity @e[type=item,limit=1,sort=nearest] Item.tag.AttributeModifiers[]
```

Comment: I added `sort=nearest` so that it would always pick up the nearest item.